# No boot option after install alongside Windows 8

Tags: laptop, windows-8, asus

I correctly managed to burn the install iso to flash drive, booted to it, installed it, and it told me that I simply needed to restart. However, on boot it gives me no option to boot to ubuntu partition but boots directly to Windows 8 without option. No partition selection, nothing. Loading the Acer/Windows boot menu only allows me to select the hard drive, not the partitions in it.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Could software like Asus instant-on be causing a problem?

Comment: The issue described in the other question seems identical to my own, however, neither fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instant on could cause problems.

Since you are boot Windows 8 successfully, I assume you have secure
boot enabled.  Some people find they can actually boot a preinstalled
W8 without secure boot enabled, but they are lucky (until their next
firmware upgrade anyway).

Check that the Ubuntu boot files got installed properly:
From the live media, mount the EFI partition (it's the `vfat` one
about 300M). It should contain a directory EFI, with an ubuntu
subdirectory.  If you get errors listing the contents of 
`<your mount point>/EFI/ubuntu`, you will have to manually delete it 
and rerun

```
sudo grub-install --uefi-secure-boot /dev/sda
```

where `/dev/sda` should be replaced by your hard disk.

The expected contents
of the ubuntu directory are `shim.efi`, `grubx64.efi`, and `grub.cfg`.
  Check that the `grubx64.efi` is the signed version.  Look at its
size, and compare it to the live media's copy of `grubx64.efi.signed`
(maybe in `/lib/grub/x64`...?).  Copy in the signed version if that's
not the one present.

Check that `/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` is the same size as `/EFI/ubuntu/shim.efi`
(or `shimx64.efi` whatever it's called).  Also, a copy of the signed
`grubx64.efi` should be present in `/EFI/Boot`.  The `bootx64.efi` is really
the bootloader used for removable media like USB, but in some error
cases, it is a (silent) fallback boot mechanism, so might as well 
fall back to grub.

Run `efibootmgr -v`  to see what possible bootloaders you have, you
expect to see both the Windows boot loader with path
`/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` and ubuntu with path
`/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`.  If the ubuntu path is `grubx64.efi` instead 
of `shimx64.efi`, then that cannot boot with secure boot enabled, so
run

```
sudo grub-install --uefi-secure-boot  /dev/sda
```

where `/dev/sda` should be replaced by your hard disk.

and recheck for a bootloader entry with shim in it.
 After running `boot-repair`, many of the bootloader files get copied around,
with many copies of shim and the originals get a "`bkp`" added somewhere
to their name.  You can always what's what by their sizes.

All you're trying to do is have the efi boot menu offer ubuntu with
through `shimx64`, and Windows through `bootmgfw` (because, sadly, some
machines cannot boot Windows from the grub menu, so this becomes the
only way).  `grubx64.efi` should be present in the same directory as 
shim, and the `grub.cfg` file in `/EFI/ubuntu` (All three could be in 
`/EFI/ubuntu`).  The `/EFI/Boot` directory may be ignored, but may also
be used as a secondary boot, set up by making `bootx64.efi` your choice of
bootloaders.

Every machine is different, good luck.